# Dump json and load in the same "with open" statement, is it possible?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to write some data into a json, and load it right away, but I'm getting a `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value...`

I want to do something like this.

```
import json

keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']

with open('keys.json', 'r+') as c:
    json.dump(keys, c)
    keys_json = json.load(c)
    print(keys_json)
```

Where as this works

```
import json

keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']

with open('keys.json', 'w') as c:
    json.dump(keys, c)

with open('keys.json', 'r') as c:
    keys_json = json.load(c)
    print(keys_json)
```

I have tried with `r+`, `w+` and even `a+` mode, using `.seek()` but I can't understand why the second one works whereas the first one doesn't.

Comment: After writing, the file pointer is at the end of the file, so reading from there returns nothing. In the second case, you open a completely new file handle where the pointer is set to the beginning.

Comment: @deceze so in theory, using c.seek(0) between the dump and the load would have to work, right? cause it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, it *does* work if you add `c.seek(0)` after `json.dump`.

Comment: ```with open('keys.json', 'w+') as c:
     json.dump(keys, c)
     c.seek(0)
     keys_json = json.load(c)
     print(keys_json)```

Comment: Yeah it works that way, thanks!